# Youtube Api Quota Limit

Tags: api, youtube, limit, youtube-data-api, quota

I am working on an app that will surely cross the existing limit of the youtube API quota. how can I contact google to provide me millions of quota limits "as a business purpose" how can I contact them so I can become their third party app partner..?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota by completing the [Quota extension request form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) for YouTube API Services.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota